# Drag and Drop removes view from the layout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm creating an android app that implements drag and drop to place views at different locations on the activity. The code runs perfectly but with a small glitch. Sometimes when I drag a view, it suddenly gets hidden or invisible from the respective activity. To bring it back to the activity I have to reload the activity by going back to previous one and come back again.

The code for drag listener is as follows:

```
public class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            return false;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            return false;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            view=(View)event.getLocalState();
            int h = view.getHeight();
            int w = view.getWidth();
            h=h/2;
            w=w/2;
            if((event.getX()-w)<0||(event.getY()-h)<0){
            }else if((event.getX()+w)>width||(event.getY()+h)> height){
            }
            else{
            view.setX(event.getX()-w);
            view.setY(event.getY()-h);
            owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            RelativeLayout container=(RelativeLayout)v;
            container.addView(view);
            relativeLayout.removeAllViews(); 
            relativeLayout.addView(text_name);
            relativeLayout.addView(text_dob);
            relativeLayout.addView(edit_name);
            relativeLayout.addView(edit_dob);
            relativeLayout.invalidate();
            view.invalidate();
            text_name.invalidate();
            text_dob.invalidate();
            edit_name.invalidate();
            edit_dob.invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            return false;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The code for touch listener is as follows:

```
    public class MyTouchListenerForEditText implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            time_up=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(time_up-time_down<2000)
            {       
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                            ((EditText)view).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
                            view.requestFocus();
                            ((EditText)view).setSelection(((EditText)view).getText().length());
                }
            }
        }
        else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {

                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                 view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            edit_name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            edit_dob.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            edit_hobbies.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            edit_ideal_person.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            edit_strengths.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            edit_weakness.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

            time_down=System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also please let me know whether we can implement drag and drop on a dynamically added view to any activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider following. It may help you out:

1. Do not set visibility of view to hide it. After adding it in "container" and removing from "relativeLayout", call View.invalidate() for both source and destination views. It will redraw the views according to requirements as seems desired.
2. In onDrag() method, return true only from ACTION_DROP where you are doing the work. In all other cases return false.

Comment: Thanks, it solved this problem of mine. I'm facing one more problem in the same code. Whenever I drag an edittext over another edittext, the edittext which was dragged goes invisible. Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: Can you please share the modified code? let us try to figure out what is happening now.

Comment: I've updated the code with the modifications as you told earlier.

Comment: You need to first do all the required changes in Views/ ViewGroups and in the end call View.invalidate().

Currently you are doing following operations after calling View.invalidate(): 
     relativeLayout.addView(text_name);
     relativeLayout.addView(text_dob);
     relativeLayout.addView(edit_name);
     relativeLayout.addView(edit_dob);

Just move these operations before View.invalidate()

Comment: I have made the required changes in the code for drag listener but, the problem is still the same. Whenever I drag an edittext over another edittext, the edittext which was dragged goes invisible.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? There may be some way around.

Comment: I want that I should be able to drag an edittext anywhere on the activity. I'm able to achieve it but, with a small glitch. as soon as an edittext gets dropped over another edittext it goes invisible. To bring it back I have to restart the activity. Is there any solution or way to bring that hidden edittext back on the activity?